# Should I leave out INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf

when I have a ViewModel, could there be cases where I can leave out INotifyPropertyChanged? I seem to get that this interface is used when you have multiple displays of a property in a GUI, so that when this property is edited, all the displays of the adjusted property get the new value. But what if you are fairly certain that UI will only have one display of the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd always implement INotifyPropertyChanged because requirements might change.

The binding mode supports OneWay and OneTime so overhead can be reduced.

Inheriting from a base class will make it easy to implement the interface so I see no real advantages of not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on a ViewModel.

Comment: Okay then, implementing it is. I got a base class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged from Josh Smith.

Answer (score 2):

I use [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver) - it generates property notification code for you. Then there is no reason why not to implement it in types that might potentially need it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your link. I upvoted you but gave accepted answer to Erno because he was first.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to leave out  INotifyPropertyChanged in two cases:

- The property is not databound
- The value of the property is never changed after the data binding is set up.

This is unlickly to be the case for a WPF ViewModel.